# Does Trino/Presto supports logical view

Tags: presto, trino

Can I create logical view over multiple views ? e.g., a view that join a bigquery table with a PG table, for example :

```
create view tv_test_view as 
select * from biggquery_table_a inner join pg_table_b on xxxx
```

checking some docs , looks like only views over hive tables are supported .

Comment: do you receive an error when you execute this?